# Have scientists demonstrated an absent protein can cause chicks to be born with scales rather than feathers (as well as reptile scales to feathers)?

Tags: biology, genetics

While researching and educating myself about evolution, I've come across an interesting claim that I'd like to learn more about, but so far, I've only been able to find the claim and no sources or evidence. For example consider following:

> - Scientists blocked the production of one protein in chicken eggs, and
>     the chicks were born with scales rather than feathers. - [Information Theory and Intelligent Design
>     Can Information Increase in a Biological System](http://www.proof-of-evolution.com/information-theory.html)
> - A single point mutation turns feathers back into scales in chickens
>     -[Feathers, Fables, Dinosaurs and Ham](http://www.noanswersingenesis.org.au/ham_more_fables.htm)

Now I did find another claim which provided a source, but it appears to be saying something different (the opposite in away), **and** the sited link (Poling, J. 1996. [Feathers, scutes and the origin of birds](http://www.dinosauria.com/jdp/archie/scutes.htm). Dinosauria on-line. Retrieved April 11, 2007) is broken:

> Experiments show that the same protein (when missing before birth)
>   that causes bird feet to stay webbed, causes bird scutes and scales to
>   become feathers (Poling 1996) - [New World Encylcopedia](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Feather)

I'm aware that the debate on the origin of feathers (and flight) is ongoing among scientists with several hypotheses being proposed, as very well described in a recent [National Geographic](http://ngm.nationalgeographic.com/2011/02/feathers/zimmer-text) article from Feb 2011. While I am interested in this in general, I'm currently trying to make sense of the claims mentioned above. Can they be substantiated, or are they baseless? I've spent about an hour searching online and haven't found anything but ambiguity (which scientists, which protein/mutation, etc).

---

### Update

I also found this related claim at [evolutionwiki.org](http://evolutionwiki.org/wiki/Archaeopteryx_was_probably_not_an_ancestor_of_modern_birds), emphasis mine:

> Scientists have actually discovered that the same protein (when
>   missing at birth) that keeps bird feet webbed causes ***reptile*** scales to
>   become feathers. Birds thus could be descended from any number of
>   reptilian species, also clear and powerful evidence for the evolution
>   of birds from reptiles.

This claim here seems to be a variation of the one above, but with *reptile* being used instead of *bird*. It is for reasons like this, and for lack of references, that I am very skeptical of these claims. They give the impression that a key gene mutation that stops the production of a protein will cause chicks to be born without feathers and instead contain scales. Or that again, a key gene mutation that stops the production of a protein will cause a developing reptile to be born with feathers instead of scales. This later claim seems even more extraordinary if you ask me.

Comment: Not answer, but an observation you might be interested in. If you look at the feet of a bird, you will see that it has scales.

Comment: @Matt that has been known for at least 25 years(I learned about it in high school biology).  It is probably going to be hard to find online sources of recent experiments for something that was discovered and proven repeatedly in the early days of DNA Experimentation.  If you are truely interested in it I would explore 70's and 80's Genetics text books from the library.

Comment: @Chad, that's interesting, after a bit further searching I come across some scientific papers that points to the protein Keratin perhaps being responsible for the scenario of my question (see [here](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012160678901793) (1978), [and here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/3956858) (1986)), but the vocabulary of the papers' abstract is beyond my full comprehension.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an exhaustive or conclusive answer, but I've come across experiments that show the following:

- In a paper from 1980, Danielle Dhouailly, Margareth Hardy, and Philippe Sengel succeeded in introducing retinoic acid (Vitamin A) to induce [feathers instead of scales to form on chicken feet](http://dev.biologists.org/content/58/1/63.full.pdf)
- Matthew Harris and John Falon were able to cause [feathers on Silkie Birds to form on legs instead of scales](http://www.livedash.com/transcript/dinosaurs_return_to_life/6222/DSCP/Sunday_February_21_2010/202457/) by "turning-on" one of two feather genes before scales form (as mentioned in a recent [Discovery Channel video](http://youtu.be/L_Uiuy-lfGs?t=1m15s))
- [An article written by Leah Lefler over at HubPages.com](http://leahlefler.hubpages.com/hub/How-to-Make-a-Dinosaur-from-Chickens) mentions that the work of Harris and Fallon mentioned above can be reversed to turn feathered areas into scales as well.
- Around the 1950-1970s [Danielle Dhouaillly, Philippe Sengel, and others performed experiments](http://www.scribd.com/doc/89691223/Dhouailly-Lizard-to-Chicken) that show it's possible to graph lizard epidermis over chick dermis, and feather-bud sized appendages appear in a hexagonal feather pattern (see figure 12 in the article, which is also linked at the end of this answer). Additionally, Lizard epidermis grafted over chick dermis can develop into scales having a large size, shape and distribution similar to those of bird scales (see figure 11).

**Conclusion:**

The references show that the scales on the feet of some birds can develop feathers instead, and that some areas where feathers normally are can have scales instead (though this later claim I'm not sure is substantiated enough, at least in the reference sited - Leah Lefler's article).

Either way, it seems to me that the claims shown in the question have a measure of truth to them, some more so than others, but are very simplified claims, likely even containing errors, that could cause a person to draw distorted conclusions. For example, the research certainly doesn't show that a baby lizard can be born today with feathers instead of scales.

[Recombinant lizard/chick experiments http://htmlimg1.scribdassets.com/6v5wbrwp4w1jbq4k/images/8-a6811b38ed.jpg](http://htmlimg1.scribdassets.com/6v5wbrwp4w1jbq4k/images/8-a6811b38ed.jpg)